# maybe this sum have approximation $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^3\approx\frac{2}{\pi\sqrt{3}n}\cdot 8^n,n\to\infty$

Tags: integration, summation, binomial-coefficients, approximation-theory

prove  or disprove  this 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^3\approx\dfrac{2}{\pi\sqrt{3}n}\cdot 8^n,n\to\infty?$$

this problem  is from when Find this limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^3}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}^3}=\dfrac{1}{8}?$$

first,follow I can't 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^3\approx\dfrac{2}{\pi\sqrt{3}n}\cdot 8^n,n\to\infty?$$
.Thank you for you help

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace's_method.

Comment: Someone else asked a nearly identical question less than a day ago:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660502/find-the-limits#comment1389671_660502

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\;\displaystyle\text{Fr}_n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^3\;$ be the $n^{th}$ 
[Franel number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FranelNumber.html) (OEIS 
[A000172](http://oeis.org/A000172) ).

Combinatorially, it is the sum of those coefficients in following polynomial expansion
where the power of $x, y, z$ are all the same.

$$(1+x)^n (1+y)^n (1+z)^n 
= \sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}\binom{n}{k} x^i y^j z^k
$$

More precisely, $$\text{Fr}_n = \sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^n 
\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}\binom{n}{k} \delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}$$
where $\delta_{ij}$ is the [Kronecker delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).
Using following integral representation of Kronecker delta,

$$\delta_{pq} = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{i(p-q)\theta} \frac{d\theta}{2\pi}$$
We can derive an integral representation of $\text{Fr}_n$:

$$ \text{Fr}_n = 8^n \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(\theta,\phi)^n \frac{d\theta d\phi}{4\pi^2}
\quad\text{ where }\quad f(\theta,\phi) = \left(\frac{\cos\theta+\cos\phi}{2}\right)\cos\theta
$$
Over its domain $[-\pi,\pi]^2$, $f(\theta,\phi)$ varies between $-\frac18$ and $1$. 
If we let $\rho(t)$ be the "density" where $f(\theta,\phi)$ taking the value $t$. We can
simplify above expression as

$$\text{Fr}_n = 8^n \int_{-\frac18}^1 t^n \rho(t) dt$$

For large $n$, the weight of the $t^n$ factor in above integral will be concentrated at $t \sim 1$. We just need to figure out the behavior of $\rho(t)$ there. The contribution from other parts of the interval will be exponentially suppressed.

Introduce variables $x = \cos\theta$ and $y = \cos\phi$. For $t \sim 1$, we have

$$\begin{align}\rho(t) 
= &\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \delta(f(\theta,\phi)-t) d\theta d\phi\\
= & \frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1 
\frac{\delta\left(\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)x-t\right) dx dy}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}}\\
= & \frac{2}{\pi^2}\int_{\frac{\sqrt{1+8t}-1}{2}}^1
\frac{\frac{2}{x} dx}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)\left(1-\left(\frac{2t}{x}-x\right)^2\right)}}
\end{align}$$
Let $u = \frac{\sqrt{1+8t}-1}{2}$. Introduce variable $z, w$ such that $z = x^2 = u^2 + (1-u^2)w$, we can simplify above as

$$\begin{align}
\rho(t) 
= &\frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_{u}^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(x^2-u^2)((1+u)^2-x^2)}}\\
= &\frac{2}{\pi^2}\int_{u^2}^1 \frac{dz}{\sqrt{z(1-z)(z-u^2)((1+u)^2 - z)}}\\
= &\frac{2}{\pi^2}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dw}{\sqrt{w(1-w)(u^2+(1-u^2)w)(1+2u-(1-u^2)w)}}
\end{align}$$
Let $t = 1-\epsilon$ and Taylor expand the integrand in terms of $\epsilon$. We get

$$\begin{align}
\rho(1-\epsilon) 
\approx &
\frac{2}{\pi^2\sqrt{3}}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dw}{\sqrt{w(1-w)}}
\left[
1
- \frac{(4w-8) \epsilon}{9}
+ \frac{(48w^2-92w+70) \epsilon^{2}}{81} 
+ \ldots
\right]\\
= & \frac{2}{\pi\sqrt{3}}\left[ 
1 
+ \frac23 \epsilon 
+ \frac{14}{27}\epsilon^2 
+ \frac{104}{243}\epsilon^3
+ \frac{266}{729}\epsilon^4
+ \ldots
\right]
\end{align}$$
Introduce yet another variable $\lambda$ such that $t = e^{-\lambda}$, above expansion
implies near $\lambda \sim 0$.

$$\rho(e^{-\lambda})e^{-\lambda} \sim \frac{2}{\pi\sqrt{3}}\left[
1 
- \frac{\lambda}{3} 
+ \frac{\lambda^2}{54} 
+ \frac{\lambda^3}{486} 
+ \frac{\lambda^4}{5832} 
+ \ldots 
\right]$$

In terms of $\lambda$, the integral representation of $\text{Fr}_{n}$ is now in a form 
which we can apply [Watson's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma).
As a result, we obtain following asymptotic expansion of $\text{Fr}_n$:

$$\begin{align}
\text{Fr}_n 
= & 8^n \left\{ \int_0^\Lambda e^{-n\lambda} \rho(e^{-\lambda})e^{-\lambda} d\lambda
+ O\left(\max\left( e^{-\Lambda}, \frac18 \right)^n\right) \right\}
\\
\stackrel{asy}{\sim} & 8^n \frac{2}{\pi\sqrt{3}n}\left[
1 
- \frac{1}{3n} 
+ \frac{1}{27n^2} 
+ \frac{1}{81n^3} 
+ \frac{1}{243n^4} + \ldots
\right]\tag{*1}
\end{align}$$

where $\Lambda$ is some cutoff for $\lambda$ where the Taylor expansion of $\rho(e^{-\lambda})e^{-\lambda}$ is valid.

Actually, once we figure out the leading behavior of $\text{Fr}_n$, there is a simpler
way to derive above expansion. Franel has shown $\text{Fr}_{n}$ satisfy following recurrence
relation:

$$n^2 \text{Fr}_n = (7n^2-7n+2) \text{Fr}_{n-1} + 8(n-1)^2 \text{Fr}_{n-2}\tag{*2}$$

If one write down a formal expansion of $\text{Fr}_n$ of the form

$$\text{Fr}_n = 8^n \frac{2}{\pi\sqrt{3}n}\left[ 1 + \frac{\beta_1}{n} + \frac{\beta_2}{n^2} + \ldots\right]$$

Plug this in $(*2)$ and match the coefficients, one will obtain:

$$\text{Fr}_n = 8^n \frac{2}{\pi\sqrt{3}n}\left[
1
-\frac{1}{3n}
+\frac{1}{3^3n^2}
+\frac{1}{3^4n^3}
+\frac{1}{3^5n^4}
+\frac{11}{3^7n^5}
+\frac{49}{3^9n^6}
-\frac{317}{3^9n^7}\\
-\frac{2797}{3^{10}n^8}
-\frac{61741}{3^{13}n^9}
+\frac{734467}{3^{14}n^{10}}
+ \ldots
\right]$$

An expansion consistent what we have got by other means and appeared in
answers in a nearly the same [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/134747/59379).

Comment: Nice job! (+1).

Answer (score 8):

I would begin by noting that one may approximate a binomial distribution for large $n$ by a normal distribution [as follows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation):

$$\binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} \sim \frac1{\sqrt{2 \pi n p (1-p)}} e^{-(k-n p)^2/(2 n p (1-p))}$$

For $p=1/2$ this simplifies to

$$\frac1{2^n} \binom{n}{k} \sim \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi n}} e^{-2 (k-n/2)^2/n}$$

Note that a sum over $k$ on the left and an integral over $k$ on the right both equal $1$.

Now cube the above equation, and integrate the right-hand side over $k$:

$$\begin{align}\frac1{8^n} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^3 &\sim \left ( \frac{2}{\pi n} \right )^{3/2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk \, e^{-6 (k-n/2)^2/n}\\ &= \left ( \frac{2}{\pi n} \right )^{3/2} \sqrt{\frac{n \pi}{6}}\\ &= \frac{2}{\sqrt{3} \pi n}\end{align}$$

The stated result follows.

I will state that this is hardly a rigorous way of proving the result, but simply follows from a consequence of the central limit theorem.

Comment: +1 This is also the hand waving way I have to get this result.

Comment: @achillehui    I did [something like that](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/563961/85343) and some people has been pushing to delete that answer. Indeed, this answer ( ${\tt\mbox{@Ron Gordon}}$ one ) is quite fine.

Comment: @FelixMarin Aside from you need to justify (or claim you are hand waving) at the second equality, everything is fine to me. I upvoted it to avoid it get deleted.

Comment: @achillehui I'll recheck that to add some 'hand savings' arguments. Thanks.